# How can I check the numeric distribution of a column in a table?

Tags: sql-server

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Phrase] (
    [PhraseId]              UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    [English]               NVARCHAR (250)   NOT NULL,
    [EnglishAscii]          AS               (ascii([English])) PERSISTED,
    [EnglishHash]           AS               (CONVERT([bigint],hashbytes('md5',[English])%(5)+(5))) PERSISTED,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PhraseId] ASC)
);
```

What I would like to do is to check the distribution of the EnglishHash column.

Is there a way that I can do a select that will show me how many rows are assigned to each value of EnglishHash?

Comment: won't distinct work

Comment: Count with group by, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT EnglishHash, COUNT(*) as [Count] FROM Phrase GROUP BY EnglishHash
```